# UILongPressGestureRecognizer does not return Tag on handler

Tags: xcode, uitableview, view, tags, uigesturerecognizer

I am adding a gesture to the cell like this

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGestureSection:)];

[gesture view].tag = indexPath.row;
gesture.minimumPressDuration = 0.5;
gesture.allowableMovement = 600;
[cell addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
```

and I am trying to get the indexPath.row

- (void)handleGestureSection:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture {

  if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
      NSLog(@"Long press Ended");

  } else if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
      NSInteger i = [gesture view].tag;
  }
  }

But is always returning 0.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You get 0 because view from UIGestureRecognizer is nil.

First you should add UIGestureRecognizer for every cell.

> ```
> UILongPressGestureRecognizer* longPressGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(gestureHandler:)];
> longPressGesture.delegate = cell;
> [longPressGesture setMinimumPressDuration:2.0];
> [cell addGestureRecognizer:longPressGesture];
> ```

And then, handle gestureHandler:

> ```
> UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer = (UIGestureRecognizer*) sender;
> CGPoint p = [recognizer locationInView:self.tableView];    
> NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:p];
> ```